# React setState inside function doesn't get read the first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, infinite-scroll, setstate

I use a `counter` starting from `0` to iterate through array chunks like `useState(vidChunks[counter])`, and using the npm *react-infinite-scroll-component* i call the `fetchMoreData` function via the InfiniteScroll component every time `vidList.length` is reached.
It works fine but the first time, where it repeats the same exact chunk of videos, and I can't understand why. It's like if it considers vidChunks[0] and vidChunks[1] the same content, but it's not, i debugged it together with the *counter* which also increases correctly.

```
const vidChunks = _.chunk(vidArray, 5)

const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
const [vidList, setVidList] = useState(vidChunks[counter])

console.log("counter "+counter)

const fetchMoreData = () => {
  setCounter(counter + 1)

  if (vidChunks[counter] === undefined || vidChunks[counter] == null) {
    setLoadText('Loaded all videos')
    return;
  }
    const newVidList = [ ...vidList, ...vidChunks[counter] ]
    setVidList(newVidList);
}
```

Comment: The new `counter` value from `setCounter` won't be available until the next render.

Comment: Can you try to change `setCounter` with arrow function `setCounter((counter) => counter + 1)`?

Comment: Tried but it didn't work :( -I also tried to put the setCounter in a function which then called the fetchMoreData function, but I had the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `counter` value from the `setCounter()` call won't be available until the next render.

Instead, create a newCounter variable from the old `counter` value, use it for your intermediate logic, then call `setCounter()` with it.

```
const fetchMoreData = () => {
  
  const newCounter = counter + 1;

  if (vidChunks[newCounter] === undefined || vidChunks[newCounter] == null) {
    setLoadText('Loaded all videos')
    return;
  }
    const newVidList = [ ...vidList, ...vidChunks[newCounter] ]
    setVidList(newVidList);
    setCounter(newCounter);
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, i did something similar but didn't work cause I was still doing setState with the counter instead of the variable newCounter